# Admin not registered error when trying to run composer-rest-server

Tags: angular, blockchain, hyperledger

I'm attempting to setup a Hyperledger Composer application using the generated Angular Frontend. I set everything up and got it working using this tutorial [here](https://medium.com/coinmonks/building-a-blockchain-application-using-hyperledger-fabric-with-angular-frontend-part-2-22ef7c77f53).

Once I got this set up, I attempted to add authentication so that I could create multiple users. I used github-passport to do this, and nothing went wrong setting it up. However, once it was set up, the composer-rest-server command now leads to an error, and I can't start the server. Here is an image of the error:

[image: Composer-Rest-Server Admin Registration Error]

Does anybody know what might be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

I think the identity which are you using to interact with the network is not registered.

I suggest you to:

1) Create a new participant

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/participant-add

2) Bind an identity to the participant

https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/managing/identity-issue

Comment: So I attempted to do that. I created a new participant, but than I can't bind an identity it leads to an error. When I first add authentication and then authorize using Github, it works perfectly with just the single user, but when I stop the rest-server and run it in multi-user mode that's when I start getting errors and I keep getting the same error I'm having above.

Comment: How do you start the rest-server in multiuser mode? Are you using the same card when you running it in single user mode?

Comment: Yes I'm using the same card. I run it using this command: `composer-rest-server -c admin@my-network -a true -m true`. After settting up authentication, testing it in single-user mode, I turn it off and restart in multi-user mode. That's when it stops working.